# How to ensure that at least 3 pods are always running even if there are any rolling updates in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I have deployed an application in k8s cluster with 8 replicas. but how to ensure that there will be at least 3 pods always running during rolling update, can anyone please suggest a solution ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can set the required values on `maxSurge` and `maxUnavailable`

```
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
       maxSurge: 25%
       maxUnavailable: 50%
    type: RollingUpdate
```

setting `maxUnavailable` to 50% will make sure that you always have 4 pods running.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the configuration option `maxUnavailable`: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#max-unavailable to guarantee that certain number of replicas are available during an update.